# What does `int` parameter in `map` function of Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, int, map-function

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
arr = map(int, input().split())
```

In the above code, map function taking two parameters, I got the understanding of the second parameter what it does but I am not getting 'int' parameter.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Which part didn't you understand?

Comment: [Are you for real?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Comment: Yes, I had read the documentation and many more other resources but I am not getting 'int' parameter in the map function. What is the use of this? @Aran-Fey

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you for doc link. I got some idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say I type `5` and then enter at the first prompt:

```
n = int(input())
```

Would take the input "5" and make it into the integer `5`. So we are going from a `string` to an `int`

Then we will get another input prompt because we have input() again in the next line:
This time I'll type `123 324 541 123 134` and then enter.

the `.split()` will split this into "123", "324", "541", "123", "134" which is a list (well a `map`) of strings. Then we'll map `int` onto them to give ourselves a `map` of `int`s rather than strings. `int` converts the strings to integers.

When checking out code it is often helpful to try things in a REPL (read execute print, looper). In your command promt just type `python` or `python3` if you have it installed or use [replt.it](http://repl.it). Type `a = "123" + "321"` then try `a = int("123") + int("321")

Wrap this with list(map(int, input().split())) to get a `list` rather than a `map`.

Comment: That's a perfect explanation! Now, How can I access the first element of arr list? @Zev

Comment: When I try to access the first element of arr list. I getting an error. ~if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())

    save = 0;
    smallNumber = arr[0]~

Comment: `arr[0]` is not working. `smallNumber = arr[0]
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: see my edit. You need `list()` around it so it isn't a map but a list.

Comment: Oh! Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

- [map(function, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) Return an iterator that applies *function* to every item of *iterable*, yielding the results.
- [int(x)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) Return an integer object constructed from a number or string *x*.

Therefore, it will return an iterable where it applied the int() function to each substring from `.split()`, meaning it casts every substring to int.

Example:

```
arr = map(int, "12 34 56".split())
arr = list(arr) # to convert the iterable to a list
print(arr) # prints: [12, 34, 56]

# This is equivalent:
arr = [int("12"), int("34"), int("56")]
```

Other example with custom function instead of *int()*:

```
def increment(x):
    return x + 1

arr = map(increment, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
arr = list(arr)
print(arr) # prints: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Oh! This string will be converted to integer!

Comment: split breaks it up and int converts each bit to integers, yes.